# Error while deploying Timerjob WSP due to DLL wsp?

Tags: sharepoint-server, timer-jobs, solution-package, solution-deployment

I have a timer job solution wsp, the name is alltimerjob.wsp, and my DLL solution name is DLL.wsp. We are trying to deploy both wsps in patch/batch. 
 It will deploy alphabetical order.so all timerjob.wsp get installed first.

First alltimerjob.wsp is installing then DLL.wsp is installing but DLL.wsp is not getting installed properly. I was getting error while installing DLL.wsp that "exception has been thrown by target of invocation".

How to avoid this error?
My timerjob wsp has a dll.                                                                        Is this error coming because of the timerjob?
If I install DLL.wsp first and then install alltimerjob.wsp, will this error not occur?

Comment: Does your timerjob solution is deploying same DLL file which DLL.WSP is deploying ?

Comment: DLL.wsp file I am having more than 20 DLL I am referring 5 DLL to my timerjob solution

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the DLL.WSP containing DLLs being referred in timejob solution, I think you should deploy DLL.wsp first because this will make sure DLL are already deployed to GAC which is required for timer job wsp.